# Bidirectional concurrent client server communication with Nodejs and Websocket

Tags: node.js, multithreading, websocket

I would like to send a video stream from server to client while the client is sending his own stream of data to the server concurrently. Is it possible to achieve this parallelism on the server (receiving while sending data) using Websocket and NodeJS?
Do we need to use two websockets with two http servers and nodejs workers or cluster for multithreading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the duplex communication using web-socket. Clustering,multi-threading is different arena all together. For reference purpose you might refer [web streaming using node.js websocket](https://medium.com/@alexcambose/webcam-live-streaming-with-websockets-and-base64-64b1b4992db8)

Comment: Right, the question is how to achieve this duplex communication (sending and receiving data in parallel on the server side) using web socket and nodejs.

Comment: You may refer  webRTC with socket  for duplex video streaming here
https://tsh.io/blog/how-to-write-video-chat-app-using-webrtc-and-nodejs/